# connecting an html editor to database

Tags: asp.net, mysql

how to connect an html editor that  is within the asp ajax toolkit so it can READ data from the database.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, did you do regular database stuff (like get value from dtabase etc), then use the Content property to set value. [See here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/htmleditor/htmleditor.aspx) for Content property.

Comment: my problem is i never used the select statement in the code-behind so i didn't get the value

Comment: In such case, I would recommend some home work here and you can setup your own http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials